# What is the importance of "this" pointer in cpp?

Tags: object-oriented, c++

I apologize for asking this intuitive question. I'm not good at programming and my recent work requires me to work a lot with SDEs. I wonder what might be the advantages using the `this` pointer?

I understand why it exists, and sometimes "this" makes it clear we are assigning value to a member variable (in the following example). For derived class, since we are able to access the base class protected or public member functions and data members even without using `this->`. I wonder what could be the other advantages?

```
class Test
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void setX (int x)
    {
        // The 'this' pointer is used to retrieve the object's x
        // hidden by the local variable 'x'
        this->x = x;
    }
    void print() { cout << "x = " << x << endl; }
};
```

Comment: I'm new to programming. I did my search and prepared my question well (using my standard). Please consider this before you downvote. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, please include code as code, not pictures.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean when you ask about "advantages". Advantages compared to implicitly accessing members? How would you rewrite `this->x = x` in a way that achieves the same effect without using "this->"?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this sort of question is off-topic here. In any case, when you create an instance (an object) of your `Test` class (and you could have several different instances), the `this` pointer allows each instance to refer to itself, from inside its own functions. Generally speaking, you don't have to pay too much attention to it, you won't be using it all that often, but it lets you do certain things. One is to access a field hidden by a local variable of the same name. You can return `this` from a method, which lets you chain method calls (search for "C++ method chaining"). 1/2

Comment: There are also uses that are less technical in nature - e.g., a developer team might decide to always write `this->` for member access, so that it's clear to everyone (when reading other people's code) that a member is being accessed, as opposed to a static function or a free function of some library, etc. I'm not personally a big fan of that. Or, you could just do it to take advantage of code completion in your IDE, to list all the members available on the instance. 2/2

Comment: I disagree that the OP is asking for assistance with explaining code. I do, however, think this question is too open-ended for this site. The "importance" of something is subjective. Even if this question were still open, it would be closed as being opinion-based. I feel like there could be a legitimate conceptual question here, but I just can't see how to make this question on-topic.

Comment: Thank you all for your help here. I'm sorry I don't know the "language" to ask this question more properly since I really don't know that much about cpp. But all of your opinions helped me a lot. I appreciate it. I will also not this kind of question again in this cite. Sorry about that.

Comment: In the context of `setX`, saying `x` alone refers to the parameter, rather than the instance field.  The parameter, so named, hides instance variables and global variables of the same name.  Thus, in the presence of that parameter hiding an instance variable, we must explicitly qualify the instance variable to use it.  In the context of `print`, saying `x` refers to the instance variable, since there is no parameter or local variable of the same name, so it is simpler to say `x` instead of `this->x`, but that would be allowed.

Comment: It is common to name a parameter the same name as an instance field, when in a setter and the intent of the parameter is to assign its value to the instance field.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder what could be the other advantages?

You can pass yourself to others. You can build others that know who you are. The [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) wouldn't be easy to write without `this`. And the classic "[getThis trick](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206)" doesn't work very well without it.  It makes subscribing easy in the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Sometimes an object needs to know where it lives so it can tell others. Just like business men need business cards full of info they already know.